# How to parse a shortcode within a shortcode?

Tags: functions, shortcode

I've created a quick function and shortcode to allow me to include logged-in user only content:

```
function content_for_logged_in($atts,$content){
    $logged_in_content = "";
    if(is_user_logged_in()){
        $logged_in_content = $content;
    }
    return $logged_in_content;  
}
add_shortcode('logged-in-content','content_for_logged_in');
```

But it doesn't parse shortcodes that are within the content, e.g.:

```
[logged-in-content]
<p>Some test content...</p>
[wpforms id="752"]
[/logged-in-content]
```

...in this case, the wpforms shortcode is displayed rather than the form.

Is there a way to alter my function so that shortcodes within the content will be parsed?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: it is described in the docu https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/shortcode/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for is named `do_shortcode` (there will also be a function `apply_shortcode` in Wordpress 5.4 that does the same). [Codex Page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)

For your example, this will work:

```
function content_for_logged_in($atts,$content){
    $logged_in_content = "";
    if(is_user_logged_in()){
        $logged_in_content = do_shortcode($content);
    }
    return $logged_in_content;  
}
add_shortcode('logged-in-content','content_for_logged_in');
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks! That's a lot simpler than my "solution" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to achieve what I need right now...

```
    function content_for_logged_in($atts,$content){
            $logged_in_content = "";
            $embedded_shortcode = $atts['embedded_shortcode'];
            if(is_user_logged_in()){
                $logged_in_content = $content;
                if(!empty($embedded_shortcode)) {
                    $logged_in_content .= do_shortcode('['.$embedded_shortcode.']');
                }
            }
            return $logged_in_content;  
        }

add_shortcode('logged-in-content','content_for_logged_in');
```

and then this:

```
[logged-in-content embedded_shortcode="wpforms id=752"]
    <p>Use the form below to upload photos for the Photo Galleries page.</p>
[/logged-in-content]
```

I’d still be interested if there’s a way to do it so that the actual shortcode can be within the $content area of the enclosing shortcode in case sometime I want to do it so that I can place the embedded shortcode somewhere else within the content, or can do multiple shortcodes within the $content area.

For my immediate needs, the above solution does the trick.